# partial fraction $\frac{4x^2-x+6}{x^3+3x^2}$

Tags: polynomials, partial-fractions

Express the following rational functions in partial fraction.

$$\frac{4x^2-x+6}{x^3+3x^2}$$

What is the form of the answer?

$\frac Ax + \frac Bx+ \frac C{x+3}$ ?

[image]

$A(x)(x+3)+B(x)(x+3)+C(x^2)$ will not get a constant term right?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about expressing such expressions in partial fractions?

Comment: Welcome to MS.E. This is not a homework site.  Therefore, you should try to solve the question yourself first.  Then we are ready to help where you are stuck.

Comment: Do you see how the second term in your suggested form is redundant? For instance, if $A=1$ and $B=0$, then $A=0.5$ and $B=0.5$ would work too. In fact, for any $A$, you can let $B=1-A$. In all of these cases, you get *one* term $\frac{1}{x}$ in the expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the factorization of the polynomial in the denominator involves a repeated term, you need to include one fraction for each power of the term up to and including the power in the factorization.

Since $x^3 + 3x^2 = x^2 (x+3)$, the form of the decomposition is
$$
\frac{4x^2 - x + 6}{x^2 (x+3)}
= \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2} + \frac{C}{x+3}.
$$